# "In" vs. "of" after the superlative form of adjectives

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives, superlative-degree, in-of

> Hanna's the youngest member **of** the team.

Why isn't it "**in** the team"?

The rule that we covered in out textbook *New Total English pre-intermediate* says that we use *in* with groups of people and places but *of* with everything else.

I do understand that it does sound perfectly well this way: "a member of". *Member* collocates with *of*, not something else. But how does the rule apply here?

Comment: Has it anything to do with the adjective, superlative or otherwise? He is a member _of_ the team, and it seems he is the youngest member (of the team).

Comment: Please avoid writing in text, not everyone is familiar with their abbreviations besides, there is no limit to the number of characters you can use in posing a question. This isn't Twitter! :)

Comment: Except that *team* takes *on* not *in* (at least in the US). Either *on* or *of* would be correct, although *of* would probably be more common.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "avoid writing in text" @Mari-Lou A

Comment: @bib: If that is addressed to me, please clarify. Otherwise, 'youngest member on the team' does not make sense, as 'member of the team' is nigh-on a compound noun. Though I suppose an MP playing in a celebrity soccer match alongside say 4 of his colleagues could be the 'youngest Member on the team'.

Comment: i guess the rule refers to the superlative adjectives 'cause it goes like this- word-for-word: Before superlatives: We usually use "in" before the names of places and groups of people: who is the youngest manager IN the company? after superlatives: we use "of" in most other cases: She is the cleverest of my three sisters. @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the term "text" is incorrect, I mean abbreviations such as: *pple*; *'cause*; *smth*.

Comment: noted:) thanks for the heads up:) @Mari-LouA

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On second thought, *member on the team* does not sound right (but *player on the team* would).

Comment: But we do say _he's playing **on** the other side_.'

Comment: @Yacatan It's a 'rule' to avoid. For what n do n sisters become a group? the 'in' in 'in the company' belongs there because it goes with 'the company': There is unrest in the company. Perhaps they mean 'before collective nouns'? But you want best man on the board / best man in the squad / best man under Col Hawkin's command / best one of the bunch ...

Comment: i haven't said that sisters were a group.. the other way round.. they are used with OF because they are not a group of people, nor a place.. in my opinion.. what the authors of the textbook imply by "a group of people" is vague though..@EdwinAshworth

Comment: Your textbook doesn't seem the best in the bunch.

Comment: well.. i'd say it's a reliable textbook.. not grammar refernce book.. that's the whole problem..@EdwinAshworth

Comment: I've seen the CGEL heavily criticised here, Yukatan, and some people treat that like a Bible. There isn't a perfect textbook, and most 'rules' should be interpreted as guidelines (or in some cases, thrown out). I'd advise you to see what most people would prefer on the internet in this sort of construction, then ask here whether most people here think they're right. (We often disagree amongst ourselves.) But Peter's answer is sound here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition does not depend on fact that it is a superlative, but on the following words. We say somebody is a "member *of* a team", so he is

> the youngest member *of* the team.

On the other hand, we say somebody is a "player *on* a team", so he is

> the youngest player *on* the team.

We say somebody is a "student *in* a class", so she would be

> the youngest student *in* the class.

And we say somebody is a "student *at* a university", so she would be

> the youngest student *at* the university.

Answer (score 3):

Both *in* and *of* are possible after superlatives. ‘An A-Z of English Grammar’ by Geoffrey Leech and others explains that ‘usually “of” is followed by a plural noun, while “in” is followed by a singular noun.’ *Of* is perhaps more usual with *team* because, although it is grammatically singular, it represents a group of people.

Comment: err... let's take the following sentence as an example: Winter's the coldest season OF the year. I don't get it how it is followed by a plural noun.

Comment: Notice the first word of the quotation: **usually**. My reference also points out that _in_ and not _of_ is used when the following noun has the general meaning of place.

Comment: that's always been a problem for me.. that USUALLY thing.. like.. what am i supposed to do with the things that the rule doesn't apply to?

Comment: Listen to and read lots of English.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely choose of. It is not a grammatical error to say 'he is the youngest member in the team', but the statement requires the question 'member of what'? It is a semantic matter. If you say 'he is the youngest member of the team' it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think *of* and *in* are both acceptable, but I would favour *of*.

In more general sense, a person or thing *of* a collective noun implies that the noun is constructed out of a collection of such members.  Something *in* a noun is more general, the noun might exist separate from the people or things who are included in it.

When you say

> He is the most committed person of the club.

you are emphasizing that the club is just a collection of people, while

> He is the most committed person in the club.

emphasizes that the club exists separate from its members.

In most cases, either *in* or *of* is acceptable, but there are stylistic preferences.  *Member* is nearly always followed by *of* because the word implies a constituent part of a group.  Similarly, *group* is nearly always preceded by *of* because a group has no identity separate from its components.  And of course, if the group is described using a plural instead of a collective noun, then always use *of*:

> She was the youngest of the players.

Superlative adjectives wouldn't change the basic distinction between *of* and *in*, but the distinction creates the potential for different interpretations of an adjective.

> She was first in the team on the racetrack.

implies that, in the ranking of all team members based on race results, she came in first.

> She was first of the team on the racetrack.

implies she was the first person of the group to arrive at the track (although I would still recommend re-writing the sentence for greater clarity).  I can't think of any similar confusion about the adjective *youngest*.

As mentioned by others in comments, "*on* the team" is another alternative, and probably more common than "in the team".  However, that wording is really specific to *team*, perhaps as an extension of the idea of a team as a list of names of people who made the cut.  You can describe a person as being "on a list", but not "on a group" or "on a class".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is how you have to understand it:

He is the youngest (member of the team).

"Member of the team" stands on its own and can be considered as a single unit.

In addition, "member" cannot really stand alone. It has to be followed by 'of the team' to make sense and this unit must be considered indivisible.

Following the same reasoning, boy can stand on its own and this is why we can say:
The youngest boy IN the team.

Answer (score 0):

According to OPG Int. By John Eastwood we use in after superlative form with places and teams e.g. Pakistan is the most beautiful country in the world.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A similar rule is already mentioned in the question. How does the specific case in question, where *of* is used with a group—"the team"—make sense? Is *member* an exceptional word that causes this?